# Calculating velocity of an object moving at 12m/s north, with 5m/s wind from the west

Tags: physics, vectors

An object moving 12m/s passes north and hits an object. Due to the wind from a west direction, it is pushed sideways at 5m/s. Find the resultant velocity.

I don't know where to start with this one, I can do the other ones just fine. It involves vector addition and subtraction. Would anyone know? I have the answers (13m/s north at 22.6 degrees).

Any help is much needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple. I hope you can imagine it: The resultant works along the diagonal of a rectangle, each of the component velocities work along the sides of it. The sides are proportional to $5$ and $12$. So, the length of the diagonal is $\sqrt{5^2+12^2}=13$.

To find the angle with the side of length $12$, note that the angle $\theta$ is such that $\tan \theta = \frac{5}{12} \implies \theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{5}{12} = 22.618864^\circ$.

For a better understanding, you may like the image:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, first time doing vectors. They seem simple and easy to apply.

Comment: @Qwerty Glad that I can help you. `:-)`

Comment: @pushpen.paul: How the heck didyou draw that figure so quick?

Comment: @Nick Using `tikz` (`latex`). That wasn't difficult. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the problem geometrically/trigonometrically, you'll be able to immediately calculate the solution.